# C++ automatic header on emacs

Tags: c++, emacs

I would like to have a header template for some of my c++ files, edited with Emacs. What I need is a header with the following information:

```
*/
|-------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Project: Name_of_proyect
|
| Created on: 
| 
| Last Modified: 
| 
| Author: author_name
|    
|------------------------------------------------------------------- 
*/
```

I would like to specify the project's and author's name on the template and the dates of creation and last modification to be updated automatically. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use library [`header2.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/header2.el) to do what you want. You can customize the header in various ways.  See Emacs Wiki page [Automatic File Headers](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutomaticFileHeaders) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using built-in `autoinsert` package with some customization. Full config is available [here](https://github.com/alexott/emacs-configs/blob/master/rc/emacs-rc-auto-insert.el).  The customization implements replacement of date, header file name, etc.

My templates you can find [here](https://github.com/alexott/emacs-configs/tree/master/auto-insert).